# I have created Labels & checkboxes based on the selection of the DropDownList, And these values must store after checked only into the sql server

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have created Labels & checkboxes based on the selection of the DropDownList, And these values must store after checked only into the sql server
pls guid me.........

```
SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("insert into EventDays(EventDay,EventStatus)values(@EventDay,@EventStatus)"); 
protected void EventDuration_DDL_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

        var paramDay = cmd2.Parameters.Add("@EventDay", SqlDbType.DateTime);
        var paramStatus = cmd2.Parameters.Add("@EventStatus", SqlDbType.Int);
        int n = Int32.Parse(EventDuration_DDL.SelectedItem.ToString());

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {

            Label NewLabel = new Label();
            NewLabel.ID = "Label" + i;
            var eventDate = Calendar1.SelectedDate.Date.AddDays(i);
            NewLabel.Text = eventDate.ToLongDateString();
            NewLabel.CssClass = "h1size";

            CheckBox newcheck = new CheckBox();
            newcheck.ID = "CheckBox" + i;
            newcheck.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(this.CheckBox_CheckedChanged);

            this.Labeldiv.Controls.Add(NewLabel);
            this.Checkboxdiv.Controls.Add(newcheck);
            this.Labeldiv.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br/>"));

            paramDay.Value = eventDate;
            paramStatus.Value = newcheck.Checked ? 1 : 0;



    }
}

private void CheckBox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    con.Open();
    cmd2.Connection = con;
    cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
}
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors? What is happening when you try to compile and run this?

Answer (score 0):

One problem appears to be in this line...

```
int n = Int32.Parse(EventDuration_DDL.SelectedItem.ToString());
```

"SelectedItem" is not going to be a number - you need to get the VALUE of the SelectedItem...

```
int n = Int32.Parse(EventDuration_DDL.SelectedItem.Value.ToString());
```